# Issue in read value from ble swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, return, bluetooth-lowenergy

Im doing a ble app in which i need to get some values from it when i tried to read value from ble device it returns nil for the first time and when i go back and execute again it returns value.In the code below im trying to fetch value of the firmware version and battery. For the first time i run the code it returns nil for the firmwire version and battery return value all the time .Please help to figure out why im not receiving value for firmwire version at first time of execution.

Here is my code

```
extension SearchDeviceViewController: CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        switch central.state {
        case .unknown:
            print("central.state is .unknown")
        case .resetting:
            print("central.state is .resetting")
        case .unsupported:
            print("central.state is .unsupported")
        case .unauthorized:
            print("central.state is .unauthorized")
        case .poweredOff:
            print("central.state is .poweredOff")
        case .poweredOn:
            print("central.state is .poweredOn")
            centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil)
        @unknown default:
            print("\(central.state)")
        }
    }
    
    //establish a connection with detected BLE device
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        var dataFound = 0
        for peripheralsFound in peripherals {
            if peripheral.identifier == peripheralsFound.identifier {
                dataFound = 1
            }
        }
        if dataFound == 0 && peripheral.name != nil {
            if !deviceIds.contains(peripheral.identifier.uuidString) {
                peripherals.append(peripheral)
                tblViewDeviceList.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
    
    //On successful connection, request for all the services available in the BLE device
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        print("connected")
        selectedPeripheral.discoverServices(nil)
    }
    //Request all the characteristics available in each services
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
        print(4)
        var count = 1
        if let servicePeripheral = selectedPeripheral.services as [CBService]? { //get the services of the perifereal
            for service in servicePeripheral {
                //Then look for the characteristics of the services
                if service.uuid.uuidString == "6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E" || service.uuid.uuidString == "180F" {
                    peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
                } else {
                    if count == 1 {
                        Alert.showAlertView(withTitle: "", withMessage: "Invalid device")
                        count = count + 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {
        print("5")
        
        if let characterArray = service.characteristics as [CBCharacteristic]? {
            for cc in characterArray {
                myCharacteristic = cc //saved it to send data in another function.
                if cc.uuid.uuidString == "6E400002-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E" {
                    writeValue()
                } else {
                    peripheral.readValue(for: cc) //to read the value of the characteristic
                    peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: myCharacteristic)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
            print("7")
            print(characteristic)
            if characteristic.uuid.uuidString == "6E400003-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E" {
               
                if let readValue = characteristic.value {
                    if let datastring = NSString(data: readValue, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) {
                        self.firmware = datastring as String
                       
                    }
                }
            }
            
            if characteristic.uuid.uuidString == "2A19" {
               
                if let readValue = characteristic.value {
                    
                    let battery = readValue.compactMap({ String(format: "%02x", $0) }).joined()
                    if battery < "60" {
                        self.batteryStatus = "CHANGE"
                    } else if battery == "" {
                        self.batteryStatus = ""
                    } else {
                        self.batteryStatus = "OK"
                    }
                    if self.firmware != "" && battery != "" {
                        let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                        let popupVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DeviceDetailsViewController") as! DeviceDetailsViewController
                        popupVC.deviceCount = defaults.integer(forKey: "devicesAdded")
                        popupVC.isNewDevice = true
                        popupVC.peripheralName = self.selectedPeripheral.name!
                        popupVC.deviceUUID = self.selectedPeripheral.identifier.uuidString
                        popupVC.fromSearch = true
                        popupVC.firmWare = self.firmware
                        popupVC.batteryStatus = self.batteryStatus
                        popupVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                        popupVC.modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical
                        self.present(popupVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
            }
        
    }
    
    func writeValue() {
        print("8")
        //Do something
        let setCmnd = "GET_FW_VERSION"
        let dataToSend: Data = setCmnd.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
        selectedPeripheral.writeValue(dataToSend, for: myCharacteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)
    }
    
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didFailToConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: Error?) {
        
    }
}
```